# Create a distinct List<String>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have three lists of `List<String>` type, named as `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`.

I add some items into `list1` then copy them to a new list which is `list2`. Then I create the `list3` to add some more items then copy them again to `list2`. However, I need `list2` to contain distinct items, so how would I exclude the duplicate items and avoid adding them into `list2`?

This is what I have tried out:

```java
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

                list1.add("String1");
                list1.add("String2");

                list2.addAll(list1);

List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

list3.add("String1");
list3.add("String3");

list2.addAll(list3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the amount of "effort" you want to put into it and the size of the lists (and hence the performance).

You could simply iterate over the elements of list3:

```
list3.forEach(s ->
{
    if (list2.contains(s))
    {
        list2.remove(s);
    }
    else
    {
        list2.add(s);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use the pattern Iterator to remove an element in a list, this will work fine for you:

```
    Iterator<String> iter = list2.iterator();
    String value = "String1";
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        if(iter.next().equals(value)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I show an example of what you are expecting. ***Before adding list3 elements to list2, we will filter out all the elements from list2 that are also present in list3***.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();


        list1.add("string1");
        list1.add("string2");
        list1.add("string4");

        list2.addAll(list1);

        System.out.println("\nPrinting List2 Elements");
        for(String element : list2){
            System.out.println(element);
        }

        list3.add("string3");
        //these will be the duplicates that we will find in list2, 
        //before adding list3, we will remove them from list 2
        list3.add("string2"); 
        list3.add("string1");

        //filtering out list3 elements from list2
        System.out.println("\nPrinting List3 Elements");

        for(String element : list3){
            System.out.println(element);
            int indexOfElement = list2.indexOf(element);
            if(indexOfElement != -1) //means it has found the element in the list
            {
                list2.remove(indexOfElement);
            }
        }

        //Now list2 doesn't contain any element that exists in list3
        System.out.println("\nPrinting List2 Elements after filtering");
        for(String element : list2){
            System.out.println(element);
        }



        list2.addAll(list3);

        System.out.println("\nPrinting List2 Elements");
        for(String element : list2){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the output with the source code [link](https://ideone.com/VIfqlR)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public final class Answer {
    private static final List<String> LIST_ONE = Arrays.asList("String1", "String2");
    private static final List<String> LIST_THREE = Arrays.asList("String1", "String3");

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // if order is not important then use a java.util.HashSet instead
        final Set<String> strings = new LinkedHashSet<>(LIST_ONE);
        strings.addAll(LIST_THREE);

        final List<String> list_two = new ArrayList<>(strings);

        System.out.println("list_two = " + list_two);
    }

}
```